# How to call on a function found on another file?

Tags: c++, sfml, identifier

I'm recently starting to pick up C++ and the SFML library, and I was wondering if I defined a Sprite on a file appropriately called "player.cpp" how would I call it on my main loop located at "main.cpp"?

Here is my code (Be aware that this is SFML 2.0, not 1.6!).

main.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "player.cpp"

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "Skylords - Alpha v1");

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw();
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

player.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int playerSprite(){
    sf::Texture Texture;
    if(!Texture.loadFromFile("player.png")){
        return 1;
    }
    sf::Sprite Sprite;
    Sprite.setTexture(Texture);
    return 0;
}
```

Where I need help is in the `main.cpp` where it says `window.draw();` in my draw code. In that parenthesis, there should be the name of the Sprite that I want to load onto the screen. As far as I've searched, and tried by guessing, I have not succeeded into making that draw function work with my sprite on the other file.
I feel like I'm missing something big, and very obvious (on either files), but then again, every pro was once a newb.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

You can use header files.

Good practice.

You can create a file called `player.h` declare all functions that are need by other cpp files in that header file and include it when needed.

**player.h**

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H    // To make sure you don't declare the function more than once by including the header multiple times.
#define PLAYER_H

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int playerSprite();

#endif
```

**player.cpp**

```
#include "player.h"  // player.h must be in the current directory. or use relative or absolute path to it. e.g #include "include/player.h"

int playerSprite(){
    sf::Texture Texture;
    if(!Texture.loadFromFile("player.png")){
        return 1;
    }
    sf::Sprite Sprite;
    Sprite.setTexture(Texture);
    return 0;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "player.h"            //Here. Again player.h must be in the current directory. or use relative or absolute path to it.

int main()
{
    // ...
    int p = playerSprite();  
    //...
```

---

Not such a good practice but works for small projects. declare your function in main.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
// #include "player.cpp"


int playerSprite();  // Here

int main()
{
    // ...   
    int p = playerSprite();  
    //...
```

Comment: Alright, you sir, are close to saving my arse. I've always heard of these damn header files, but never really looked into them, they're pretty important, eh? But here's another question, once I've done this, and I imported it into the "main.cpp", what would my "main.cpp" file look like in the window.draw area, how would that go about?

Comment: @Safixk Yes. When your code starts to get bigger they become extremely important. I suggest you do create header files if you have more than cpp file

Comment: Alright, trying your new code that you've just sent me, check back in 5

Comment: Question, in my player.h file - "#idndef PLAYER_H" "#idndef" is not recognized preprocessing device - Would you by chance have meant "#ifndef"?

Comment: Also, how would my "main.cpp" file look in the "window.draw" area?

Comment: @Safixk You just call it like as if it was in the main file `int p = playerSprite()` see the edit.

Comment: @startdust_ Alright, I'm sorry, I'm completely lost. Could you please just show me, or explain in depth a bit more?

Comment: @Safixk I think you need to do a lil bit of reading up :). I can't explain everything in here. Just look for some C++ tutorials. You will catch up fast. It is not as complicated as it seems. At least not this part. :)

Comment: I did everything as mentioned but my android application is crashing when it is trying to call cpp method from another class

Comment: How does `main.cpp` know to look for code in `player.cpp`?

Comment: isn't it bad practice to have includes in the header file?

Comment: pardon me for being basic, so basically the .h file act similar to interface in java?

Comment: @AaronFranke the compiler doesn't need the definition(it doesn't need to see the `player.cpp`), it only needs the function prototype(which is done by header or manually doing forward declaration). It is the linker that connects the definition in `player.cpp` to `main.cpp`.

Answer (score 29):

Small addition to @user995502's answer on how to run the program.

`g++ player.cpp main.cpp -o main.out && ./main.out`

Answer (score -3):

You can create a project and include both the main.cpp and player.cpp files there.

Then this should be work inside the main.cpp file.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "player.cpp"
```

Comment: Never include a source file.